# Hybrid Pen Marks on AP Mid Carrys

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently read about using Hybrid-Penetration Marks instead of pure Magic-Penetration.

I know that it is a poor choice if you're not gonna harrass your lane opponent with auto-attacks. However, assuming you play it right and you auto your opponent during laning, is the increased auto-attack damage output worth sacrificing some of your early magic pen? I dont want to start an discussion like "*Discuss Pros and Cons!*". I just want to know if this is a viable option or if it is just plain stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would only run them on champions that use auto attacks as part of their combos naturally (such as akali or kayle and potentially someone like ziggs), as they can take advantage of the benefits of armor penetration throughout the game and is not being used as an early game lane winner.

Dual pen runes on ranged AP mids had a spike of popularity due to the ease of harassing melee mid champions (which were and still are popular) with long range auto-attacks, so it was lucrative and useful to have this extra armor penetration to win your lane with.  However, now that Doran's shield is so popular, I feel that if the enemy melee mid laner (such as zed, katarina etc) makes this item, it makes harassing them with auto attacks almost not worth the effort due to the constantly reduced damage and consideration how the enemy creeps will react (attacking your champion, which causes the wave to push to their tower and you potentially take damage/get ganked).

For this reason, I would stick with the full magic pen runes rather than hybrid pen in your typical mid laning situation.  Ideally, you would want 2 pages (one with full and one with hybrid) and decide at champion select if you think it's a possibly advantageous matchup.

Answer (score 1):

It varies by play-style,
Alex Ich runs most of his APC with hybrid penetration,
Faker runs most of his APC with pure penetration,

Note that early points in penetration counts the most.

Example, if 5 mpen is worth 10x gold, than 10 mpen is worth about 18x gold, not 20x.

So getting 5 mpen and 5arpen is worth more than pure penetration so if you have the runes you should always use them when appropriate.

When you are in champion select here is a useful if else case for picking runes

```
if(opponent at mid is melee)
  use hybrid penetration
else
  use magic penetration
```

For champions:

```
if(you are : Akali,Corki,Ezreal,Janna,Jax,Kayle,Kennen,KogMaw,Lulu,Nidalee,Poppy,Teemo)
  definitely use hybrid penetration
else if (you are :Diana,Evelynn,Karma,Lux,Morgana,Nami,Orianna,Zyra,Zilean,Ziggs,Twisted Fate,Tristana,Sona)
  hybrid penetration optional according to style
else
  use magic penetration
```

Comment: **Example, if 5 mpen is worth 10x gold, than 10 mpen is worth about 18x gold, not 20x.**  Can't say I agree with this.  Penetration typically grows in strength the more of it you have and your statement essentially says it weakens.  The more you have the closer you drive to 0 resistances and true damage.  Same reason that the higher their base resistance is the weaker flat penetration is.

Answer (score 0):

You only use Hybrid runes on some match ups . For example Fizz into Leblanc , LB isn't known for her armor scaling but , Armor Pen vs 0 armor = 10% basic true damage from W + Runes . Let alone it's so MUCH easier to last hit with armor pen runes because ap users like ahri or lb or even tf have such a hard time last hitting to freeze lane .